# Segfault: Tracking frequency of unique characters in a string and storing in array

Tags: arrays, c

I have another C question. This time I am trying to count the frequency of each character in a given string. Each unique character will be stored in a node structure and added to an array of node structs to later be used in a Huffman coding implementation (heap/binary tree already constructed, just having trouble with these frequencies).

This is my code:

```
typedef struct node {

  unsigned int freq;
  char character;
  struct node *left, *right;

} node;

//constructor for node struct
node* Node (char c, node* left, node* right){
  
  node* myNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

  myNode->freq = 0;
  myNode->character = c;
  myNode->left = left;
  myNode->right = right;

  return myNode;

}

node** storeFreq = malloc(sizeof(node) * 256);
  
  char c;
    int totalNumOfCharacters = 0;

    //read the file character by character
    while ((c = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
      printf("%c\n", c);

      if (totalNumOfCharacters == 0) {
          
          //make the node
          node* myNode = Node(c, NULL, NULL);

          //put it in the list
          storeFreq[0] = myNode;

          //increase the frequency of the character by one
              storeFreq[0]->freq++;

              //increase the total character count
              totalNumOfCharacters++;

        }

      else {

      for (int i = 0; i < totalNumOfCharacters; i++){

        //if the character is already in the table
        if (storeFreq[i]->character == c){

          //increase the frequency of the character by one
              storeFreq[i]->freq++;

        }
        
        //if it's not in the table
        else {

          //make the node
          node* myNode = Node(c, NULL, NULL);

          //put it in the list
          storeFreq[totalNumOfCharacters - 1] = myNode;

          //increase the frequency of the character by one
              storeFreq[i]->freq++;

              //increase the total character count
              totalNumOfCharacters++;

        }
        }
      }


    }


    fclose(inputFile);


//print frequencies
    int i = 0;
    while (i < totalNumOfCharacters) {
      printf("i: %d", i);
      printf("Character: %c | Frequency: %d\n", storeFreq[i]->character, storeFreq[i]->freq);
      i++;
    }
```

This is the valgrind output:

```
==292846== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==292846== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==292846== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==292846== Command: ./a.out encode message.txt message_codeTable.txt
==292846== 
T
h
==292846== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==292846==    at 0x1095F4: main (file.c:181)
==292846== 
==292846== Invalid read of size 1
==292846==    at 0x1095F4: main (file.c:181)
==292846==  Address 0x4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==292846== 
==292846== 
==292846== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==292846==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4
==292846==    at 0x1095F4: main (file.c:181)
==292846==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==292846==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==292846==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==292846==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==292846==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==292846== 
==292846== HEAP SUMMARY:
==292846==     in use at exit: 15,880 bytes in 6 blocks
==292846==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 0 frees, 15,880 bytes allocated
==292846== 
==292846== LEAK SUMMARY:
==292846==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==292846==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==292846==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==292846==    still reachable: 15,880 bytes in 6 blocks
==292846==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==292846== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==292846== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==292846== 
==292846== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==292846== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==292846== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I trace this segmentation fault? I need a sanity check.

Comment: You have not done any free(), it is really normal those memory leaks then

Comment: yes but the implementation is giving a segmentation fault, so it's also reaching outside of memory somewhere and I'm not sure where

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger to isolate where the segfault is happening, and then you can figure out what that code is doing wrong that is causing the fault. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is an excellent time to start learning.

Comment: first I would try to solve those memory leaks

Comment: can we please see all the code, this code is not even correct syntax. It has exectable statements outside functions. No main....

Comment: fgetc returns an int not a char

Comment: your 256 malloc should be sizeof(node*) * 256 not sizeof(node) * 256. this is not the cause of your error, you are just wastng memory

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line:

```
==292846==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 0 frees, 15,880 bytes allocated
```

For every memory allocation like malloc, you should always free those bytes of memory you have allocated so that the compiler can use those bytes.

So if you make this for example:

```
  node* myNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Before the program is finished, a `free(node)` should be done so that no memory leak happens

For the segmentation fault you are probablly trying to access some invalid adress of memory, I would also suggest to use the debugger as it is really helpful in this context

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
      //increase the frequency of the character by one
      storeFreq[i]->freq++;
```

you are using `i` as the index, this has already run off the end of the array, you mean:

```
      //increase the frequency of the character by one
          storeFreq[totalNumCharacters - 1]->freq++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, should've been adding to totalNum rather than totalNum - 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).